# Implementing a digital delay line in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a digital delay line in C, which delays the time sequence by an integer number. The background is audio signal processing and I want to add some delay as about 10 ms which is 441 samples when sampling rate is 44100 Hz. The input audio stream is send to me block by block, so I'm expected to output the same size of signal. The block size is genenrally 1024 samples or something like that.

I have a pointer `*data` which is the time sequence of length `blockSize`, and a pointer `*buffer` of length `N` that is used to save the delayed `N` samples for the usage of the next block. Here we can assume that `blockSize` > `N`.

I know how to realize it if `data` has the length of `blockSize + N`: first copy the last `N` samples to the beginning of `data`, and then write samples from `data + N`:

```
memcpy(data, data + blockSize, N * sizeof(*data));
write_data(data + N, blockSize);
read_data(data + N, blockSize);
```

But I have no idea how to do it with `data` and `buffer`, two pointers without consecutive memory addresses.

If I have `data` of length `blockSize` and `buffer` of length `2 * N`, I can write something like:

```
void delayline(int *data, int *buffer, unsigned blockSize, unsigned N)
{
memcpy(buffer + N, data + blockSize - N, N * sizeof(*data)); // copy the last N samples of data to the second half of buffer
memmove(data + N, data, (blockSize - N) * sizeof(*data)); // delay the remaining blockSize - N samples by N
memcpy(data, buffer, N * sizeof(*data));  // copy the first half of buffer to data, these samples are from the previous block
memcpy(buffer, buffer + N, N * sizeof(*data));  // copy the second half of buffer to the first half for the use of next block
}
```

But I don't know how to do it if `buffer` only has a length of `N`. Is it possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't tag C++ unless you are willing to receive C++ answers.

Comment: I think I understand the idea of a delay line but I don't understand what is going on with your buffers, and your block size and how you want the `delayline` function to behave.  Your last paragraph is confusing.  Do you think you could describe that better?  Maybe write a little test code for `delayline` that passes some data to it, then prints the output from the function, and tell us what you want to get printed.  (It's OK if your test code doesn't actually work, since you don't have a working implementation of `delayline` yet.)

Comment: @paddy OK, thank you, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I've updated some background and a simple working example with a larger memory allocation.

Comment: Your existing implementation doesn't make much sense to me.  You never actually write anything to the memory from `data[0]` through `data[N-1]`, so that can't be right.  Did you get some of the copy operations backwards?

Comment: @DavidGrayson Sorry, I confused the `dst` and `src` in the last two lines of `memcpy`. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my initial idea about how to make a delay line.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define DELAY_SIZE 5
int delay_data[DELAY_SIZE];
int delay_data_index = 0;

// The output of this function is equal to the input
// that was passed to it 5 iterations ago.
// (The first five outputs are fixed to 0.)
int delay(int x)
{
  int r = delay_data[delay_data_index];
  delay_data[delay_data_index] = x;
  delay_data_index++;
  if (delay_data_index >= DELAY_SIZE) { delay_data_index = 0; }
  return r;
}

void out(int x) {
  printf("%d\n", x);
}

int main() {
  out(delay(1));   // 0
  out(delay(2));   // 0
  out(delay(3));   // 0
  out(delay(4));   // 0
  out(delay(5));   // 0
  out(delay(6));   // 1
  out(delay(7));   // 2
  out(delay(8));   // 3
  out(delay(9));   // 4
  out(delay(10));  // 5
  out(delay(11));  // 6
  out(delay(12));  // 7
}
```

It certainly won't be the most efficient thing ever because it moves data one `int` at a time, but you should be able to use it as a starting point and then optimize it later if needed.

Comment: Hi David! I'm doing with audio stream block by block (or frame by frame), so the first 5 samples are not supposed to be zero, they should be the last 5 samples that were not output in the previous frame.

Comment: @DSPnovice the idea provided by David Grayson is efficient in that we don't need to move entire data in the buffer but just one by moving the index instead. It completely emulates the behavior of a delayline aka fifo buffer. It will output the initialized or undefined data until the buffer is filled with the input at the very beginning as long as the `delay`.

Comment: @DSO novice:  What do you mean by "last 5 samples", if we are talking about the very first sample?  Defining something by saying what it is *not* is quite confusing.  If your system has just started up, and the delay size is 5, what are the first 5 outputs outputs your delay line will give?